# Why am I getting ORA-00922: missing or invalid option while trying to create a table?

Tags: sql, syntax, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE form1
  (
     empcid   VARCHAR2(25),
     empname  VARCHAR2(100),
     empid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empdgn   VARCHAR2(50),
     empdob   DATE,
     empadd   VARCHAR2(200),
     empcom   VARCHAR2(15),
     empshare VARCHAR2(10),
     empsdoj  DATE,
     empedoj  DATE,
     constraint pkform1 primary key (empcid, empname, empid, empdgn)
  ); 

CREATE TABLE deposit
  (
     loanid    VARCHAR(25),
     openbal   DECIMAL(20, 3),
     subcrp    DATE,
     subamt    DECIMAL(20, 3),
     totdep    DECIMAL(20, 3),
     subamtint DECIMAL(25, 3),
     cumuint   DECIMAL(20, 3),
     empcid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empname   VARCHAR2(100),
     empid     VARCHAR2(25),
     empdgn    VARCHAR2(50),
     constraint pkedeposit primary key (loanid),
     constraint fkform1 foreign key (empcid, empname, empid, empdgn) references
     form1
  ); 

CREATE TABLE sharecapital
  (
     loanid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empedoj   DATE,
     empshare  VARCHAR2(10),
     shareint  DECIMAL(20, 3),
     loandt    DATE,
     loandeduc VARCHAR2(25),
     dividend  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     sharetot  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     empcid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empname   VARCHAR2(100),
     empid     VARCHAR2(25),
     empdgn    VARCHAR2(50),
     constraint fkdep foreign key(loanid) references deposit),
     constraint fkscform1 foreign key(empcid, empname, empid, empdgn) references
     form1
  );
```

It's showing the error when I execute **sharecapital** table "missing or invalid option"

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: While posting a question, providing the right formatting will help a lot if you want some decent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE sharecapital
  (
     loanid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empedoj   DATE,
     empshare  VARCHAR2(10),
     shareint  DECIMAL(20, 3),
     loandt    DATE,
     loandeduc VARCHAR2(25),
     dividend  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     sharetot  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     empcid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empname   VARCHAR2(100),
     empid     VARCHAR2(25),
     empdgn    VARCHAR2(50),
```

**`constraint fkdep foreign key(loanid) references deposit),`**

```
     constraint fkscform1 foreign key(empcid, empname, empid, empdgn) references
     form1
  );
```

should be

```
CREATE TABLE sharecapital
  (
     loanid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empedoj   DATE,
     empshare  VARCHAR2(10),
     shareint  DECIMAL(20, 3),
     loandt    DATE,
     loandeduc VARCHAR2(25),
     dividend  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     sharetot  DECIMAL(25, 3),
     empcid    VARCHAR2(25),
     empname   VARCHAR2(100),
     empid     VARCHAR2(25),
     empdgn    VARCHAR2(50),
```

**`constraint fkdep foreign key(loanid) references deposit,`**

```
     constraint fkscform1 foreign key(empcid, empname, empid, empdgn) references
     form1
  );
```